# IF TIME NOT BETWEEN SHEETS

Tags: function, google-sheets

this is my first thread in this forum.
i want to ask, the proper functions on google sheets to calculate this "SLA" Column.

the case i facing is, i want made the "SLA" Column refers to "Start Time" is not between work hour ( 07.00 AM To 17.00 PM ). or the simple word is whenever start time not in work hour the SLA will shows zero or 00:00:00.

also i have start time and end time to calculate to the "SLA".
how to combine those functions, so i can get the result if on work hour or off work hour

thanks

[the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkL1z.png)

Comment: DON’T SHOUT AT US.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output